# Ambiguous list comprehension ranges in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I want to generate all tuples `(m, n)` such that `m+2n <= 2nmax - 1` in python 3.9. It is easily done via

```
nmax = 4
a = [(m, n) for n in range(0, nmax) for m in range(0, 2*(nmax-n))]
>>> [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3)]
```

However I noticed that if I instead do

```
nmax = 4
b = [(m, n) for n in range(0, nmax+1) for m in range(0, 2*(nmax-n))]
>>> [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3)]
```

(`n` goes to `nmax+1` instead of `nmax`) then

```
a == b
>>> True
```

I first thought it was an edge case for the `nmax` I was picking, but I get the same behaviour for all `nmax<100`. I do not quite understand why there is an ambiguity here. Is it because of the range of `m` depends on `n`? If so, what would be the "correct" bounds?

Comment: `range(0, 0)` is empty so that extra last iteration (`n == nmax`) does nothing. If you're confused about why a list comprehension does something, it's almost always helpful to write it as a regular loop and step through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because of the range of m depends on n

Yes.

---

1. Outer `range(0, nmax)` means last value is `nmax-1` that means inner loop final bounds is

   ```
   2 * (nmax - n)
   2 * (nmax - nmax + 1)
   2 * 1 
   2
   ```
2. Outer `range(0, nmax + 1)` means last value is `nmax` that means inner loop final bounds is

   ```
   2 * (nmax - nmax)
   2 * (0)  
   0
   ```

So the round you add for `n` creates an empty `range` for `m`

---

Detail by the values

```
for n in range(0, nmax + 1):
    values = list(range(0, 2 * (nmax - n)))
    print(f"{n=}   {2*(nmax-n)=}   {values=}")


n=0   2*(nmax-n)=8   values=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
n=1   2*(nmax-n)=6   values=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n=2   2*(nmax-n)=4   values=[0, 1, 2, 3]
n=3   2*(nmax-n)=2   values=[0, 1]
n=4   2*(nmax-n)=0   values=[]                    # generated by the +1 in the 'n' range
```

Answer (score 2):

In the last iteration of your second case, `n` is equal to `nmax`. This makes `2 * (nmax - n)` zero. `range(0, 0)` is an empty iterator, so there is no inner loop for the last outer loop of `n`, so nothing gets added to the list comprehension, and it's as if the last loop never happened. So you get `a == b` is `True`.

You want `m <= 2(nmax - n) - 1`, i.e. `m < 2(nmax - n)`, which is what you already get from your first loop.

When `n == nmax`, this condition gives `m <= -1`. Using `m in range(0, ...)` automatically means `m >= 0`. It's fairly obvious that both these conditions can never be true, so no pair of `(m, n)` will satisfy `m, n >= 0; m + 2n <= 2 nmax - 1` when `n == nmax`